# Asp.net Core System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

So I am trying to use LINQ to get data from the database using the context. However, I'm getting the following Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression '(categories) => categories.Name' 
by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.
```

This should place insert the list into ViewData["Categories"] so I can use it in the view, not quite sure why this is happening. Why is it complaining about the EF?

Below is my get request in the controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{  
    ViewData["Categories"] = _Context.MenuCategories.SelectMany(categories => categories.Name).ToList(); 
    return View();
}
```

Below is my drop down which I am trying to populate

```
<select asp-for="Category" class="form-control" asp-items="@(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) 
@ViewData["Categories"]"></select>
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `SelectMany` and not just `Select`? `SelectMany` would return a collection of `char`?

Comment: @JSteward Right that makes sense. I have now run into another issue which I dont know how to get around. I'm getting this exception: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem]'.

Comment: That's a separate question, but you're binding `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with an `IEnumerable<string>` you need to map your collection of strings to a collection of items that can be shown by a select list

Comment: @JSteward Thank you, it works now. I just created a new select list item for each category name inside the select.